MongoDB docker container connection localhost not working
I am currently working on a remote VM.
I set up a Container via a docker-compose.yml file.
Everything seems fine. I wrote a script to set up a User for the Database with an initial password (besides the admin) on Docker startup.
I can connect to the Database from my local Desktop via the MongoCompass (used the credentials of the "non-admin" user) but i cant connect to the Database from the VW the Docker is running on directly.
Maybe some of you know why.
docker-compose.yaml :
version: '3.6'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: email-mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGODB_DB: ${MONGODB_DB}
      MONGODB_USER: ${MONGODB_USER}
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh:ro

.env :
MONGODB_DB=someDatabase
MONGODB_USER=someUsername
MONGODB_PASSWORD=someInitialPassword

init.sh :
set -e
mongosh <<EOF
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: '$MONGODB_USER',
  pwd:  '$MONGODB_PASSWORD',
  roles: [{
    role: 'readWrite',
    db: '$MONGODB_DB'
  }]
})
EOF

working connectionstring for Compass (local PC):
mongodb://someUsername:someInitialPassword@vmaddress:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&directConnection=true

pythoncode:
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

# MongoDB-Connectiondetails
mongo_host = "vmaddress"
mongo_port = 27017
mongo_username = "someUsername"
mongo_password = "someInitialPassword"

try:
    # Create a MongoDB-Client
    client = MongoClient(f"mongodb://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@{mongo_host}:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&directConnection=true")
    
    # Get List of DB 
    db_list = client.list_database_names()
    
    print("MongoDB connection successfull.")
    print("Datenbases on Server:", db_list)

except ConnectionFailure as e:
    print("Connection to MongoDB failed:", e)

except Exception as e:
    print("An Error occurred:", e)

Error from executing python:
Connection to MongoDB failed: vmaddress:27017: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 667d0c03c495fd3d26fab99c, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('vmaddress', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('vmaddress:27017: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

docker container ls:
6c834ed695a4   mongo:latest                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago      Up 2 days    0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp                              email-mongo

I am out of any ideas.
Maybe there is a typo i missed or somethind i literally forgot.
I hope you can help,
Max

At this stage I'd pick wireshark and check what's goin on on the wire.  Timeout is likely comes from TCP level.

unfortunately the docker is running in an VM. I only have a terminal.

As far I see the connection from my pythoncode does not appear on the logs of the container. The Connection from the Compass does show up.

There are still a tcpdump & similar, but they are not that convenient.  How do you proxy traffic from vmaddress:27017 to localhost:27017 for compass connection?

for compass I use the external IP of the VM (docker is running on that)
The Pythonscript is executed on that VM via terminal.
Is that answering the question?

ok, let me ask it another way - assuming you are using bridged network, there must be some firewall rules added to your VM when you publish a port to let the traffic coming through. It should apply to all interfaces, but you are sayin the local loop aint working. So I wonder what do you have in your iptables.

As I understand, you are running the python script directly from the VM's terminal, not inside a container. In that case, try to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for mongo_host

Hey,
I tried.
Also no success.
I can ping the external ip of the VM but even that address does not work.
The Port is open (checked via nmap).
